# A short story about an astronaut on Mars

Tags: story-identification, mars

When I was a kid I had a book that had many older sci-fi short stories. One of my favs was about an astronaut who was the only one left alive after a crash-landing on Mars. His food and water ran out but he eventually found an uninhabited Martian city that was not compatible with human life. In the end the city changed him to a Martian where I assume he lived happily ever after.

Comment: This is very light on details, although you might be having trouble remembering any more, please check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: @David I'm sure you're right, this is yet another request for "The Enchanted Village" by A. E. van Vogt. Barry, you can read it for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Other_Worlds_05v02n01_1950-07_cape1736#page/n5/mode/2up). Please let us know if this is the one you were looking for.

Comment: YES! This is it. Thank you so much. Ahhhh the memories!

Comment: @Barry If you want to find the book you read it in as a kid, you might find it in [this list of titles](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56655) or you might recognize one of [these covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?56655).